# jQuery sliding border bottom for horizontal navigation bar / menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, sliding

I had an idea for a horizontal navigation bar that the page you were on would have an underline or bottom border that when you went to a < li > in the menu that underline / bottom border would, at about a medium speed, move to the < li > your mouse is hovering over. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Sorry for not providing sample code. I just have no idea where to start

Here's the menu, just for some example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li
{
display:inline;
}
li.active
{
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
a
{
text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is there a negative vote?

Comment: I did not downvote but it is probably because you have not posted what you have tried

Comment: I don't think your explanation is very clear. Post some code for say, the horizontal bar. When you said 'page you were on would have a... bottom border' it made me think of a footer.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is what I think you are after. When you mouseover an item in a horizontal navigation bar it should animate a marker to move under that item. You can do this by giving the marker a fixed position and animating its top and left properties to position.

http://jsfiddle.net/dBxn8/

```
$('li').mouseover( function() { 
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5;
    var left = $(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2);
    $('#marker').stop().animate( { top: top, left: left  }, 2000 );
});
```

Comment: yeah! just like that, but i'd want it to move only left and right, and it would be a line beneath the text